# Pulling Out Ids From Separate Objects And Plugging Into Function

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, object

I am trying to plug individual id's into a function to pull log outputs for each id. These ids are inside objects inside a larger object. I cannot figure out how to call these id's individually in order to print out the log report for each object.

objects

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {id: "60844b1f5ce50a40c1adfc32", rdbmsJobId: null, sqoopJobId: "30471e65-c9b9-40e0-b27f-472769480f0c", status: "FINISHED", progress: 100, …}
1: {id: "60844b1f5ce50a40c1adfc33", rdbmsJobId: null, sqoopJobId: "1e74fb62-4a61-420b-9c78-e005007eb17e", status: "FINISHED", progress: 100, …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Function

```
  getLogDataById(id: string){
    this.logService.getLogById(id).subscribe(logRes => {
      this.logReport = logRes
      console.log("Log report is: " + this.logReport)
    })
  }
```

Expected Output

```
{
    "id": "60844b1f5ce50a40c1adfc34",
    "jobId": "60844b1f5ce50a40c1adfc32",
    "log": "2021-04-24 16:45:20,180 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7\n2021-04-24 16:45:21,084 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.\nWarning: /opt/sqoop/../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.\nPlease set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.\nWarning: /opt/sqoop/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.\nPlease set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.\nWarning: /opt/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.\nPlease set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.\nWarning: /opt/sqoop/../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.\nPlease set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.\nJob Created and Saved to Sqoop.\nSqoop Job Submitted to Yarn\n2021-04-24 16:46:27,894 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable\n2021-04-24 16:46:28,051 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032\nContainer: container_1618958577187_0219_01_000001 on ip-172-31-50-48.us-west-2.compute.internal_43829\nLogAggregationType: AGGREGATED\n=====================================================================================================\nLogType:stderr\nLogLastModifiedTime:Sat Apr 24 16:46:26 +0000 2021\nLogLength:1722\nLogContents:\nApr 24, 2021 4:46:02 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register\nINFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.JAXBContextResolver as a provider class\nApr 24, 2021 4:46:02 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register\nINFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler as a provider class\nApr 24, 2021 4:46:02 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register\nINFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.AMWebServices as a root resource class\nApr 24, 2021 4:46:03 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate\nINFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'\nApr 24, 2021 4:46:03 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider\nINFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.JAXBContextResolver to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope \"Singleton\"\nApr 24, 2021 4:46:04 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider\nINFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope \"Singleton\"\nApr 24, 2021 4:46:06 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider\nINFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.AMWebServices to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope \"PerRequest\"\nlog4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster).\nlog4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.\nlog4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.\n\nEnd of LogType:stderr\n***********************************************************************\n\n\nEnd of LogType:stdout\n***********************************************************************\n\nContainer: container_1618958577187_0219_01_000003 on ip-172-31-50-48.us-west-2.compute.internal_43829\nLogAggregationType: AGGREGATED\n=====================================================================================================\nLogType:stderr\nLogLastModifiedTime:Sat Apr 24 16:46:26 +0000 2021\nLogLength:227\nLogContents:\nLoading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.\n\nEnd of LogType:stderr\n***********************************************************************\n\n\nEnd of LogType:stdout\n***********************************************************************\n\nContainer: container_1618958577187_0219_01_000002 on ip-172-31-50-48.us-west-2.compute.internal_43829\nLogAggregationType: AGGREGATED\n=====================================================================================================\nLogType:stderr\nLogLastModifiedTime:Sat Apr 24 16:46:26 +0000 2021\nLogLength:227\nLogContents:\nLoading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.\n\nEnd of LogType:stderr\n***********************************************************************\n\n\nEnd of LogType:stdout\n***********************************************************************\n\nIngestion Finished"
}
```

Comment: Expected output would be helpful

Comment: I have updated the post with the expected output